# visudo + how to enable user to delete any file under /var/log/http

Tags: linux, redhat, sudo

I want to enable user - "Ertop" to delete any file or directory under  /var/log/http by update the visudo

I have redhat machine version 6.x

user name is Ertop

I set the following in visudo but not sure it this syntax is ok

```
Ertop ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: rm -rf /var/log/http/*
```

or

```
Ertop ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: sudoedit /var/log/http/*
```

Comment: What happened when you tested this ?

Comment: I cant test it for now because not have the password for this user

Comment: Why don't you use a user that you do have the password for to test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I set the following in visudo but not sure it this syntax is ok

the visudo command will check your syntax for you and stop you from saving the file if the syntax is incorrect

```
visudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 112 <<<
```

According to the versions of visudo I have to hand `visudo version 1.8.6p{3,7} visudo grammar version 42` on CentOS 6.8 and 7.3.1611 your syntax is incorrect.